For a concave increasing function, is the total area of the gap between the integral and the trapezia finite?

Let $f:\mathbb{R}_{>0}\to\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ be increasing and concave,
with $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}{f(x)}=+\infty.$ Does the
following limit necessarily exist?
$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\int_{1}^{n} f(x) dx - \frac{1}{2}\left(
 f(1) + 2\sum_{k=2}^{n-1} f(k) + f(n) \right) \right)$

It is the total area in the gap between $f(x)$ the trapezia (when using the trapezium rule with equal widths). If we did not use equal width-trapezia, then it would be easy to come up with counter-examples.
I had a look here, but I didn't see anything useful.
The idea behind the proposition is that large changes in curvature of $f$ will result in a greatly decreased gradient of $f,$ and so the area in upcoming gaps will be small.
I'm also not aware of any methods to find the exact value of $\displaystyle\int_{1}^{n} f(x) dx - \frac{1}{2}\left(
 f(1) + 2\sum_{k=2}^{n-1} f(k) + f(n) \right)$ for common functions $f.$ So maybe $f(x)=\log x$ is a counter-example, but I don't know how to find this out.

The Euler-Maclaurin formula looks related

@whpowell96 but that's the difference between the integral and the rectangles, which is easier than my question. The difference between the integral and rectangles (all with width $1$) tends to infinity $\iff \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=+\infty,$

$$
\Delta_n = \int_{1}^{n} f(x) dx - \frac{1}{2}\left(
 f(1) + 2\sum_{k=2}^{n-1} f(k) + f(n) \right)
$$
is a nondecreasing sequence, so it suffices to show that $(\Delta_n)$ is bounded above. Since $f$ is concave, we have
$$
\int_{k-1/2}^{k+1/2} f(x) \, dx 
= 2\int_0^{1/2} \frac{f(k-h) + f(k+h)}2\, dh
\le 2\int_0^{1/2} f(k) \, dh = f(k) 
$$
for all integers $k$, that is known as the lower bound of the Hermite–Hadamard inequality for convex functions. Together with the monotonicity of $f$ we can estimate the integral as
$$
 \int_1^n f(x) \, dx = \int_1^{3/2} f(x) \, dx + \sum_{k=2}^{n-1} \int_{k-1/2}^{k+1/2} f(x) \, dx + \int_{n-1/2}^{n} f(x) \, dx \\
\le \int_1^{3/2} f(x) \, dx + \sum_{k=2}^{n-1} f(k) + \frac 12 f(n)
$$
so that
$$
 \Delta_n \le \int_1^{3/2} f(x) \, dx - \frac 12 f(1)  \, .
$$
This is an upper bound and proves the existence of the limit.
The facts that $f(x) > 0$ or that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$ were not used in the proof.

See here for a short and simple proof of the Hermite–Hadamard inequality.

@JohnBentin: Thanks. I have added some intermediate steps to make it self-contained, that is essentially the same approach as in that article (integrating Jensen's inequality).

I like your proof better than mine.

@DavidK: I think the underlying idea is the same: The integral of $f$ over $[k-1/2, k+1/2]$ is not greater than the area of the trapezoid whose upper side is a tangent line at the graph of $f$ at $x=k$.

I see the similarities. They differ in the economy of construction to realize that idea, among other things.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}_{>0}\to\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ be concave
with $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = +\infty$.
(This implies that $f$ is increasing.)
For every positive integer $n$ let
$$ F(n) \triangleq  {\int_{1}^{n} f(x)\,\mathrm dx}
 - \frac12 \left( f(1) + 2\sum_{k=2}^{n-1} f(k) + f(n) \right). $$
The question is whether the limit of $F(n)$ as $n \to\infty$ exists.
For $k$ a positive integer, the quantity $F(k+1) - F(k)$ is the (signed) area above the top of the trapezoid between $x=k$ and $x=k+1$ and below the graph of $f(x)$.
Due to the concavity of $f$, this area is never negative.
Also since $f$ is concave,
for $x \in [k,k+1]$ (for $k$ a positive integer)
we have
$$ f(k) + (x - k)f'_+(k+1) \leq f(x) \leq f(k) + (x - k)f'_+(k) $$
where $f'_+$ is the right-sided derivative of $f$.
So the entire graph of $(x,f(x))$ for $k \leq x \leq k+1$ lies within a triangle whose vertices are $(k,f(k))$, $(k,f(k)+f_+'(k))$, and $(k,f(k)+f'_+(k+1))$
and whose area is $\frac12 (f'_+(k) - f'_+(k+1))$.
The line connecting $(k,f(k))$ to $(k+1,f(k+1))$
(the top edge of the trapezium between $x=k$ and $x=k+1$)
also lies within this triangle, as does the entire region of area $F(k+1) - F(k)$ between that trapezium and the graph of $f(x)$.
This implies that $0 \leq F(k+1) - F(k) \leq \frac12 (f'_+(k) - f'_+(k+1))$.
We can write $F(n)$ as a telescoping sum,
\begin{align}
F(n)
&= (F(n) - F(n-1)) + (F(n-1) - F(n-2)) + \cdots + (F(2) - F(1)) \\
&\leq \frac12(f'_+(n-1) - f'_+(n)) + \frac12(f'_+(n-2) - f'_+(n-1))
 + \cdots + \frac12(f'_+(1) - f'_+(2)) \\
&= \frac12(f'_+(1) - f'_+(n)).
\end{align}
Since $F(n)$ is the sum of positive areas $F(k+1) - F(k)$, $F$ is an increasing function.
But since $f$ is increasing, we have $f'_+(n) \geq 0$, therefore
$$ F(n) \leq \frac12 f'_+(1), $$
that is, $F(n)$ is bounded.
Perhaps one could make the bound sharper, but the existence of a finite bound is enough for this purpose. (Estimating the value of the limit is another matter.)

Note that the value of $F(n)$ is unaffected when we replace $f$ by $f$ plus any constant. So the restriction to a positive codomain is not necessary;
we could let $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ provided that
$[1,\infty) \subseteq I \subseteq \mathbb R$.

This proof assumes the existence of $f'$.

@JohnBentin: That is correct, but it can be fixed by working with the left or right derivative, which exists at every point.

@MartinR, Thanks, I've made that change.
